# SugarCRM Update Records through backend

Tags: soap, set, sugarcrm

Another framework studying today and just started about 4 days now. My goal is to add a new button in the detail view with function, specifically in Contacts module. I added a new field called "active_c" which is a check box. If the checkbox is check then he clicks the button the field then is unchecked, which mean the contact is inactive.

I have done the new button part and I already found where to put my code upon clicking the button (it is on the module controller right?). What I am lacking is to update the record to check or uncheck, or true or false, or 1 or 0.

I have found some using soap but it does not work for me. Heres a part of my code.

```
  $client = new nusoapclient('http://localhost/sugarcrm/soap.php?wsdl',true);
    //login
    $auth_array = array(
        'user_name' => $current_user->user_name,
        'password' => $current_user->user_hash,
        'version' => '6.5.2'
    );
  $session = $client->call('login',array('user_auth'=>$auth_array,
             'application_name'=>'SugarCRM'));
  $session_id =  $session['id'];
```

My "$session" retruns nothing if I printed it out. Without session['id'] I cannot proceed to *set_entry*.

I'm using only localhost.

Help, How do I do this guys?

Regards,
Ronel C.

Comment: Are you trying to add a checkbox/button to the Sugar detail view or to a third-party app? If it's an external app, how is it currently pulling in the data?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply guys. My intention really was, is to update a record everytime the button is clicked and I found the answer. So stupid of me to go into much complex way.

What I did was (in case somebody else has problem):

```
//Instantiate the class - for me its Contacts
$contact = new Contact();
// Use retrive
$data = $contact->retrieve($record_id);
$data->first_name = 'Pedro Penduko';
$data->save($record_id);
```

And thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test with `127.0.0.1` in your URL instead of localhost like `http://127.0.0.1/sugarcrm/soap.php?wsdl`

Comment: it looks an XML file opened. What does that mean?

Comment: Hey I got an error in Sugar - 
"Error: Could not connect to the Sugar Server. Please check your Proxy Settings value in the System Settings admin panel. " Is there something I should do first?

Comment: Yes you should. Also, make sure the server name in the URL matches that in the 'site_url' directive in the config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the older soap.php entrypoint, but the newer services/ one as the older is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2010/11/11/web-services-in-your-own-language-part-1-php-2/